# Do trinomials weaken the Alternating Step Generator?

Tags: cryptanalysis, alternating-step

The Alternating Step Generator was proposed by Christoph G. Günther: [*Alternating step generators controlled by de Bruijn sequences*](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-39118-5_2.pdf), in [proceedings of Eurocrypt 1987](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-39118-5_2). It's perhaps the conceptually simplest CSPRNG producing bits at a constant rate. Its best-known cryptanalysis is by Shahram Khazaei, Simon Fischer, and Willi Meier: [*Reduced Complexity Attacks on the Alternating Step Generator*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.83.5814), in [proceedings of SAC 2007](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-77360-3_1).

The ASG combines three Linear Feedback Shift Registers. To produce a bit:

- advance LFSR2
- according to its low-order bit, advance LFSR0 or LFSR1
- output the XOR of the low order bits of LFSR0 and LFSR1

[image: ASG]

The key is the initial state of the LFSRs (assumed to be random and independent bits, save for the state of each LFSR not being all-zero). It is customary to use primitive binary polynomials of distinct degree $n_i$. In the initial exposition, LFSR2 is modified to generate a de Bruijn sequence, that is the output sequence has an extra zero inserted after $n_2-1$ consecutive zeroes. But this detail makes no cryptanalytic difference, since that point in the sequence is reached with negligible probability for $n_2$ large enough for security.

**Would using binary *trinomials* sizably reduce the cryptanalytic resistance of the ASG?**

The rationale to want to use trinomial:

- it minimizes implementation cost in hardware (each additional coefficient cost an XOR gate), and the number of reads in a software implementation using indexes in circular buffers;
- it reduces the choice, allowing to make the primitive trinomials "[nothing up my sleeve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nothing_up_my_sleeve_number)";
- we can use the [compact table of primitive binary trinomials](https://www.jjj.de/mathdata/all-trinomial-primpoly-short.txt) compiled by [Jörg Arndt](https://www.jjj.de/).

Comment: You could begin by asking "why is the original ASG so hard to break". One possible explanation is that the random clocking causes LFSR0 and LFSR1 to behave as "sticky channels" with no error correcting bits. What is the channel capacity of such a channel?  Now invoke Yao's XOR lemma by XOR'ing both sticky channels and you have something very hard to analyze.

Comment: @WilliamHird what is the channel capacity of "sticky channels with no error correcting bits"?

Comment: @kodlu:  I don't know, let's "channel" (pun intended) Michael Mitzenmacher and find out ,  :-)

Comment: @kodlu: Actually, I just saw your profile, it says you dabble in coding and information theory. What do you think the channel capacity is for the IID sticky channel if it is just a raw channel, ie., no error correction bits?

Comment: I was asking since I am unsure what the definition of the sticky channel is

Comment: @kodlu: I think if you Google "sticky channel" you will hit on Mitzenmacher's paper on the sticky channel. That's what I was alluding to in my previous comment.

Comment: @kodlu:  I'm not an expert but my intuition is that noisy channels, whether they are insertion-deletion, sticky, Additive Gaussian Noise, 50% bit rate error, ect., can be seen as pseudorandom permutations of the sent bits (channel input) when viewed asymptotically , there are no codewords sent to help the adversary recover the original bitstring.  Is this a definition of a one way permutation? I don't know, mayber we can get an expert to comment here.